avformat_write_header return error code when trying to write video with G711U audio avi file
I'm trying to make an avi file from a video/audio stream. When audio is AAC it works fine. But I cannot pack G711U audio.
  av_register_all();
  avcodec_register_all();
  av_log_set_callback(nullptr);

  av_format_context_ = avformat_alloc_context();
  if (!av_format_context_)
  {
    std::string error_msg = "Failed to allocate avformat context";
    log_->Error(error_msg);
    throw std::runtime_error(error_msg.c_str());
  }

  av_format_context_->oformat = av_guess_format("mp4", filename.c_str(), NULL);
  strcpy(av_format_context_->filename, filename.c_str());

  AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_MULAW);
  av_format_context_->oformat->audio_codec = codec->id;

  audio_stream_ = avformat_new_stream(av_format_context_, codec);
  if (audio_stream_ == nullptr)
  {
    log_->Error("Can not create audiostream.");
    return false;
  }

  AVCodecContext& codec_context = *audio_stream_->codec;
  if (avcodec_copy_context(audio_stream_->codec, av_format_context_->streams[1]->codec) != 0)
  {
    log_->Error("Failed to Copy Context");
    return false;
  }

  audio_stream_->time_base = { 1, codec_context.sample_rate };

  if (av_format_context_->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
    codec_context.flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

  log_->Info("Init output {}", filename);
  av_dump_format(av_format_context_, 0, filename.c_str(), 1);

  int ret = avio_open(&av_format_context_->pb, filename.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
  if (ret < 0)
  {
    log_->Error("Can not open file for writing.");
    return false;
  }

  ret = avformat_write_header(av_format_context_, NULL);
  if (ret < 0)
  {
    log_->Error("Can not write header.");
    return false;
  }


Here avformat_write_header() returns -22. What's wrong here? Which data should I supply to this function?

If you are on a POSIX system, AVERROR wraps a POSIX error code as a negative value.  POSIX error 22 is EINVAL "invalid argument" on my system.

Ok, what's wrong with the argument?

In your code you tried to create MP4 container format output file instead AVI: when you've provided short name in av_guess_format as first parameter, it has more weight for decide output format than file name extension (https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/libavformat_2utils_8c-source.html#l00198).
MP4 container does not support PCM data including G.711. Please look on this page for details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats
